# How progress work on scrolling on my div not window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

Here, My progress bar and that progress bar move when I scroll window.

But I want when i scroll window it detect div not window. 
I write code for window and it perfectly worked for on window scroll how I have done it.

Here is my code

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
            documentHeight = $(document).height(),
            windowHeight = $(window).height();
            scrollPercent = (scroll / (documentHeight-windowHeight)) * 100;
            var position = scrollPercent;

    $("#progressbar").attr('value', position);

    });
```

```css
progress {
        height: 6px;
        width: 100%;
        position:fixed;
        margin-left: -48px;
        margin-top: -20px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div type="slideshow" id ="slide">
<section>
  <header>date </header>
  <section>content</section>
</section>
<section>
  <header>date </header>
  <section>content</section>
</section>
<section>
  <header>date </header>
  <section>content</section>
</section>
<section>
  <header>date </header>
  <section>content</section>
</section>
</div>
```

What should i do to write this code on my div.
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you update your snippet into a working one,.  You can include 3rd party plugins like jQuery, etc from the add external library feature.

Comment: Just use `scrollTop ()` on your div like `$('#slide').scrollTop ()`. In combination with `$('#slide').get(0).scrollHeight()` (note the `get(0)`) you can calcuate the percentage of your scroll-postions.

Comment: Surely it should be quite obvious that if you want to apply it to the element instead of the window, you swap your window object in your selector for the the selector of the element you want to put it on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit to provide you with a solution i think you wanted to have. The same way you checked `window` for `scrollTop` and `height` can be used on a `div`. Please be aware that, to get this example working, I restricted height of the div to `100px`.

```js
$('#slide').scroll(function () {
  var scroll        = $(this).scrollTop();
  var scroll_height = $(this).get(0).scrollHeight;
  var height        = $(this).height ();
  var percent       = scroll / (scroll_height - height) * 100;

  $("#progressbar").text (percent);
});
```

```css
#progressbar {
  border:     1px solid #000;
}

#slide {
  height:     100px;
  border:     1px solid #000;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressbar">0</div>

<br><br>

<div type="slideshow" id="slide">
  <section>
    <header>date </header>
    <section>content</section>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>date </header>
    <section>content</section>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>date </header>
    <section>content</section>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>date </header>
    <section>content</section>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>date </header>
    <section>content</section>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>date </header>
    <section>content</section>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>date </header>
    <section>content</section>
  </section>
  <section>
    <header>date </header>
    <section>content</section>
  </section>
</div>
```